# How to install gems in vendor dir in Docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, bundler

Following is my dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-slim as Builder

ARG FOLDERS_TO_REMOVE
ARG BUNDLE_WITHOUT
ENV GEM_HOME="/vendor/bundle"
ENV PATH $GEM_HOME/bin:$GEM_HOME/gems/bin:$PATH

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

ADD https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN apt-key add /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg && rm /tmp/yarn-pubkey.gpg
RUN echo 'deb http://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y --fix-missing --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    git \
    tzdata \
    libgeos-dev \
    nodejs \
    yarn

WORKDIR /code

COPY Gemfile* package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --check-files

RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4 -N && \
    bundle config set without $BUNDLE_WITHOUT && \
    bundle config set deployment 'true' && \
    bundle config set no-cache 'true' && \
    bundle install -j4 --retry 3 

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

When I build the image and run it I get

```
bundler: command not found: rails
```

When I remove the line `bundle config set deployment 'true'` it works perfectly fine.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What if you drop the line that isn't working and modify the last line to `bundle install --deployment -j4 --retry 3`?

Comment: I don't the problem is that, gems are getting installed in vendor directory but I think the later stage don't know where to find them and is looking for gems in system gems

Comment: To debug this, you can do a docker run overriding the CMD with bash. Inside there, execute a bundle list to check installed gems and double-check relevant env variables.